# How come when I CURL vs using URLLIB2, I get different results?

Tags: python, http, url, curl

```
curl -L http://tumblr.com/tagged/long-reads
```

This is the result: http://pastebin.com/XtQVubBp

That response is different from

```
def download(url):
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return f.read()
html = download('http://tumblr.com/tagged/long-reads')
print html
```

This is the result of 2nd one: http://pastebin.com/MdzrhBZv

Why? **I want download() to return the same thing curl does. What should I do?**

Here's the CURL request headers.

```
$ curl -v -L http://tumblr.com/tagged/long-reads
* About to connect() to tumblr.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 50.97.149.179... connected
* Connected to tumblr.com (50.97.149.179) port 80 (#0)
> GET /tagged/long-reads HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
> Host: tumblr.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-length: 0
< Location: http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/long-reads
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/long-reads'
* About to connect() to www.tumblr.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 50.97.143.18... connected
* Connected to www.tumblr.com (50.97.143.18) port 80 (#0)
> GET /tagged/long-reads HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
> Host: www.tumblr.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 07 May 2012 22:09:01 GMT
< Server: Apache
< P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"
< Set-Cookie: tmgioct=iVajmrL8Wj8YffLTthjFyqYn; expires=Thu, 05-May-2022 22:09:01 GMT; path=/; httponly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Tumblr-Usec: D=266934
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
```

**EDIT: I WILL OFFER a 500 BOUNTY TO WHOEVER SOLVES MY PROBLEM RIGHT NOW.**

Comment: Read the docs on both closely.  My experience with curl/urllib2 has been that curl does lots of best guess magic with headers and such that urllib2 doesn't do.  Especially around things like content-type and the actual HTTP methd (GET/PUT/etc).

Comment: How can I make download() return the same thing curl does?

Comment: I think what he's getting at is that you haven't actually told us what the difference is.

Comment: I pasted the difference.

Comment: Where do you see there a difference, pls just post the relevant parts, we have more things to do then cheking two files with 300 lines.

Comment: Are you concerned about the whitespace/newline differences?  If so, you might want to look in to what eol characters the various systems that created and are reading this file use, and see if it is perhaps some sort of encoding thing that either curl or python is missing out on converting correctly.

Comment: @sr2222 click both links. You'll notice that the responses are completely different.

Comment: No, no they aren't.  I didn't go line by line through the whole thing, but aside from whitespace, the content in the 2 files looks the same from a quick scan of the 2.

Comment: @sr2222 Yes, those responses are COMPLETELY DIFFERENT. I don't know why you're giving me a hard time.

Comment: Because they aren't.  What is the first syntactically significant line in either file that does not have a syntactically equivalent line in the other file?  The formatting is different, which is odd, but as senderle says below, that's probably due to headers.

Comment: @sr2222 the one with urllib2 does not have blog posts. The one with curl has blog posts. I'm trying to crawl blog posts. Get it? The 2nd one does NOT have blog posts

Comment: Oh, down around line 300.  I see.  See, this is why you should tell people more specifically where things are different.  Also helps to be polite to people willing to help you do your job for free.

Comment: @sr2222, sorry I thought you were trolling or something

Comment: Do you have access to the request headers so we could at least eliminate that as a cause?

Comment: Ok, cool.  Now can you try setting the header to those values in the request via urllib2.Request as laid out by senderle below?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly how to make them look the same; you'd have to know which headers `curl` is using and reproduce them in `urllib2`. But once you know the headers `curl` uses, it *should* be as simple as setting those headers in a `Request` object:

```
>>> moz_req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'})
>>> pyt_req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Python-urllib/2.6'})
>>> moz_url = urllib2.urlopen(moz_req)                                          
>>> moz_str = moz_url.read()
>>> moz_url.close()
>>> pyt_url = urllib2.urlopen(pyt_req)
>>> pyt_str = pyt_url.read()
>>> pyt_url.close()
>>> moz_str == pyt_str
False
```

When I do the following, I get a page full of blog posts.

```
import urllib2

def download(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'}
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    url = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = url.read()
    url.close()
    return page

html = download('http://tumblr.com/tagged/long-reads')
page = open('page.html', 'w')
page.write(html)
page.close()
```

But then, I checked, and I get the same result even without setting headers. Something else is wrong...

Comment: I'd +1 you again if I could.  :)

Comment: @senderle  I used your code, but I still did not get blog posts. Weird. I'm on EC2. Could the IP be blocked? But why would cURL work from that same machine if the IP is blocked?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but could your python interpreter be running under a different user (with different perms and restrictions), than your CLI user?

Answer (score 0):

If you use https instead of http, atleast I am getting results. BTW this is not a problem with latest library.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), You might require taking a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to make it more valuable,

Comment: I gave a correct answer, can u please atleast upvote it?